# AdMob - iOS Implementation RewardBasedVideoAd

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am trying to implement a RewardBasedVideoAd for iOS using C# in Xamarin and I just can't seem to get it to work. This is what I have so far and it does not go into any of the delegate functions. Any help or advice is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    public class AdMobImplementation : UIViewController, 
    IRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate
    {
        public AdMobImplementation()
        {
            RewardBasedVideoAd.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
RewardBasedVideoAd.SharedInstance.LoadRequest(Request.GetDefaultRequest(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313");
            }
        public void DidRewardUser(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd, AdReward reward)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("rewarded");
        }

     public void DidFailToLoad(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd, NSError error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Reward based video ad failed to load with error: {error.LocalizedDescription}.");
        }

        public void DidReceiveAd(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reward based video ad is received.");
        }

        public void DidOpen(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opened reward based video ad.");
        }

        public void DidStartPlaying(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reward based video ad started playing.");
        }

        public void DidClose(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reward based video ad is closed.");
        }

        public void WillLeaveApplication(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reward based video ad will leave application.");
        }
}
```

Comment: Did your problem been solved?

Comment: I have the same behavior - no delegate methods ever get called. I assume that it might be something related to iOS linker - native bindings from `IRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate` like `DidRewardUser` or `DidClose` are simply stripped away during linking phase. However, I'm not able to validate this, it's only an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Problem finally solved!
You don't need to deal with `IRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate`.
All you have to do is inherit your class from `RewardBasedVideoAdDelegate` and override all necessary methods like:

```
public class AdMobImplementation : RewardBasedVideoAdDelegate
    {
        public AdMobImplementation()
        {
            RewardBasedVideoAd.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
RewardBasedVideoAd.SharedInstance.LoadRequest(Request.GetDefaultRequest(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313");
            }
        public override void DidRewardUser(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd, AdReward reward)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("rewarded");
        }

     public override void DidFailToLoad(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd, NSError error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Reward based video ad failed to load with error:{error.LocalizedDescription}.");
        }

        public override void DidReceiveAd(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reward based video ad is received.");
        }

        public override void DidOpen(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opened reward based video ad.");
        }

        public override void DidStartPlaying(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reward based video ad started playing.");
        }

        public override void DidClose(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reward based video ad is closed.");
        }

        public override void WillLeaveApplication(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reward based video ad will leave application.");
        }
}
```

Hope this helps to anyone looking for solution :)

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot this weekend.

Comment: Welcome :) Don't forget to mark as answer and upvote if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**
Different from BannerView. Because you used the testUnitID provided by google .So you need set the TestDeviceId.You will get error info in the output like

> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices =
>   @[ kGADSimulatorID ] or @[@"xxxxxxxxxxx"] if you use real device;

**Solution:**

> If you use the simulator

```
var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
request.TestDevices = new[] {Request.SimulatorId.ToString() };
RewardBasedVideoAd.SharedInstance.LoadRequest(Request.GetDefaultRequest(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313");
```

> If you use the real device

```
var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
request.TestDevices = new[] {"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"};
RewardBasedVideoAd.SharedInstance.LoadRequest(Request.GetDefaultRequest(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313");
```

I used the abovecode and it works fine.